# Sequelize Migration Not Recognizing Existing Table

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am trying to figure out the reason why sequelize is pre-pending `public` to my SQL query tablename on a migration, which I believe is directly related to the reason why I am seeing `SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "public.organization" does not exist`. `organization` is the name of a table so this shouldn't be the problem with the migration, but the `public` does appear to be something sequelize is pre-pending and throwing off the raw SQL.

```
"sequelize": "^3.19.2",
"sequelize-cli": "2.7.0",
```

Here is the migration file:

```
'use strict';

    module.exports = {
      up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        return queryInterface.addColumn('organization', 'admin_id');
      },

      down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        return queryInterface.removeColumn('organization', 'admin_id',{
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          before: "admin"
        });
      }
    };
```

Here is a truncated version of the error:

```
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  message: 'relation "public.organization" does not exist',
  parent: 
   { error: relation "public.organization" does not exist
...
  sql: 'ALTER TABLE "public"."organization" ADD COLUMN "admin_id" INTEGER;' },
```

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem?